# ORA-00936: missing expression while executing in C#.

Tags: c#, oracle, insert, blob

I am writing a function for inserting BLOB file in to ORACLE. While executing the code I am getting the error stating that `ORA-00936: missing expression`.

My Code:

```
public static void DatabaseFilePut(MemoryStream fileToPut, OracleConnection con)
    {
     try
      {
       byte[] file = fileToPut.ToArray();
       const string preparedCommand = @"INSERT INTO user_account_statement (statement_id,session_key,login_id,user_id,account_number,
       from_date,todate,ipaddress,
       create_date_time,STATEMENT_FILE) VALUES(1073,'fe79e0345986b5a439c26f731234868b53f877366f529',
       2335,'204254','108142',to_date('2014-08-23 16:45:06','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
       to_date('2014-08-23 16:45:06','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),
       '106.79.126.249',to_date('2014-08-23 16:45:06','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'),file)";
       using (var sqlWrite = new OracleCommand(preparedCommand, con))
       {
        sqlWrite.ExecuteReader();
       }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
       {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
       }
    }
```

Please advise where I am going wrong.

Comment: The problem is the last value you're providing, `file`. That isn't your `byte[]` reference, as there is no link between that and the reference in the statement. Oracle seems to be giving that particular error because it's a reserved word; something else would give ORA-00984. You need to bind the object to the variable in the statement as a stream; but I have no experience of doing that in C# so someone else will have to add an answer if you don't know how to do that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I specified parameter for 'file'

```
sqlWrite.BindByName = true;
                var blobparameter = new OracleParameter
                {
                    OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Blob,
                    ParameterName = "ssfile",
                    Value = fileToPut.ToArray()
                };
                sqlWrite.Parameters.Add(blobparameter);
```

and changed parameter name too. because the parameter name `file` is ORACLE's reserved word. So it might create another problems.